# Restart a specific reverse ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, modem, tunneling, mobile

I have multiple machines in the wild that open reverse ssh connections to my server. Each machine out there is using a different reverse ssh port, which I use to differentiate between the machines. I use these tunnels to log into the machines from the server (obviously):

```
me@server:~$ ssh -p 2219 root@localhost
Last login: Sun Jun  7 00:18:44 2015 from localhost
root@remote_machine:~#
```

The remote machines are using quite different access technologies (DSL, VSAT, GPRS/EDGE/3G/4G), so the endurance of the reverse ssh connection differs somewhat - and here apparently lies the problem.

This is what `nmap` lists after a longer idle period (ie. no ssh tunnel has been forcefully restarted, see below):

```
me@server:~$ sudo nmap -sS -p 1000-3000 --open localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-07 11:09 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000014s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 1988 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1133/tcp open  unknown
1270/tcp open  ssserver
1356/tcp open  cuillamartin
1590/tcp open  unknown
1760/tcp open  unknown
1772/tcp open  unknown
1823/tcp open  unknown
1825/tcp open  unknown
1842/tcp open  unknown
1907/tcp open  unknown
2078/tcp open  unknown
2168/tcp open  unknown
2185/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
me@server:~$
```

Now, this is way too few connections, so let's kill them all and wait for the external connections to come back:

```
me@server:~$ for i in $(ps axww|grep ssh_key_used_for_reverse_connctions|grep sshd|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|cut -d " " -f 1); do sudo kill -9 $i; done
me@server:~$
```

Ok, all connections are gone:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-07 11:13 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000014s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
All 2002 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
```

Let's wait (the remote machines try every 30 seconds to establish a new connection) and see what's coming in now:

```
me@server:~$ sudo nmap -sS -p 1000-3000 --open localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-07 11:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000015s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 1950 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1125/tcp open  unknown
1129/tcp open  unknown
1133/tcp open  unknown
1155/tcp open  unknown
1156/tcp open  unknown
1157/tcp open  unknown
1162/tcp open  unknown
1176/tcp open  unknown
1185/tcp open  unknown
1198/tcp open  unknown
1215/tcp open  unknown
1269/tcp open  unknown
1270/tcp open  ssserver
1343/tcp open  unknown
1345/tcp open  unknown
1351/tcp open  equationbuilder
1356/tcp open  cuillamartin
1420/tcp open  timbuktu-srv4
1432/tcp open  blueberry-lm
1541/tcp open  rds2
1590/tcp open  unknown
1698/tcp open  unknown
1743/tcp open  unknown
1760/tcp open  unknown
1772/tcp open  unknown
1773/tcp open  unknown
1812/tcp open  unknown
1823/tcp open  unknown
1825/tcp open  unknown
1842/tcp open  unknown
1859/tcp open  unknown
1900/tcp open  upnp
1907/tcp open  unknown
2002/tcp open  globe
2030/tcp open  device2
2031/tcp open  unknown
2032/tcp open  unknown
2033/tcp open  glogger
2035/tcp open  imsldoc
2058/tcp open  unknown
2078/tcp open  unknown
2093/tcp open  unknown
2159/tcp open  unknown
2168/tcp open  unknown
2169/tcp open  unknown
2180/tcp open  unknown
2185/tcp open  unknown
2186/tcp open  unknown
2219/tcp open  unknown
2221/tcp open  unknown
2228/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.16 seconds
me@server:~$
```

Ahh, much better.

**Now, my questions:** Even in the first scenario with little open connections, `ps axww|grep ssh_key_used_for_remote_connections|grep sshd|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'` shows *a lot* more ssh connections then are actually open, so the connection seems to silently die in the background *without the remote machine noticing it*.

**A. Is there a better way of implementing the reverse ssh connections**, for example any ssh options I might have missed that make the remote machine notice a dead/stuck connection better?
This is the script that's running on the remote machines to open up the reverse ssh tunnel:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  ssh -i /some/dir/reverse-ssh.key -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -nNTv -R $(grep -o "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" /some/dir/id):localhost:22 reverse_ssh_user_name@office.radiopark.biz
  sleep 30
done
```

So I already use `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3`. `/some/dir/id` holds a four digit number which each machine uses as it's reverse ssh port, from the servers point of view the reverse ssh port.

**B. Is there a better way to `kill` *only* unresponsive reverse connections**, leaving all "working" connections intact? For now I kill all of them, but that seems crude and wrong. `ps` won't let me see the port id and I would need to make the connection of reverse ssh port and ssh's PID on my server somehow.

I have looked into `autossh` but that seems to re-do what my scripts do(?).

`mosh` is out of the question as it uses UDP connections (which oftentimes don't go through at all) and random ports above 60000 (which don't get through, either).

Comment: What you seem to be experiencing is TCP-in-TCP meltdown: the "outer" connections are mostly fine (which is why they aren't killed), it's the tunneled ones that are stalling.  Consider using some UDP-based VPN instead.  Regardless, `ServerAliveInterval=5` and `ServerAliveCountMax=3` are probably too low and actually amplify the problem, perhaps replace them with something like 30 and 6 respectively.  And add `TCPKeepAlive`, `ClientAliveInterval`, and `ClientAliveCountMax` on the server side.  Disabling `CheckHostIP` on clients wouldn't hurt either, but is not related to your problem.

Comment: I'll try that - will let you know how/if things improved. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to kill those connections whose inner tunnels are dead?

Comment: I'd expect minor improvements at best, like I said, the problem comes from running TCP-in-TCP.  As for killing the stale connections, I don't think there is any simple solution.  For ~50 clients you really should be looking at IPsec rather than SSH tunnels.

Comment: I would recommend against IPsec for reasons of complexity. Personally I'm a big fan of OpenVPN, which works over UDP and can therefore be NATed way more easily. I do agree with the general recommendation of using a VPN rather than SSH tunnels for this sort of thing, though (i.e., this should probably be an answer rather than a comment...)

Answer (score 1):

This will show you the processes using the tunnel:

```
netstat -tnp | grep :2219 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

I can't reproduce your dead connections, but this should work

```
for i in $(seq 2000 2030) do
  if !nmap -p $i localhost
    netstat -tnp | grep 2222 | grep '/ssh *$' | awk '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's#/ssh##' | xargs kill
  fi
end
```

Comment: `netstat: option requires an argument -- p` (macOS Monterey zsh)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you change your client script to manually checks reverse tunnel status by comparing command `hostname` localy vs remote-over-tunnel `hostname` (the same comp):

```
#!/bin/bash

tunport=$(grep -o "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" /some/dir/id)
while true; do                    # -f (detached, foreground)
   ssh -i /some/dir/reverse-ssh.key -fnNT -R $tunport:localhost:22 rsuname@server.addr
   while true; do
      if [ "$(hostname)" = "$(ssh -p $tunport rsuname@$srvip hostname)" ]; then
         sleep 30
      else # kill local and remote process
          pkill -f "ssh .* -R $tunport:localhost"
          ssh rsuname@server.addr "lsof -ti tcp:$tunport | xargs -r kill"
          break # to tunnel re-init
      fi
   done
done
```

seems like bulletproof solution, answers A and B, and eliminates the need for tcpkeepalive, client/server aliveInterval/countMax options and admin interventions.